# What is a more efficient way to accomplish validate/save()'ing a Django object while abstracting away the repetition?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I highly doubt that the way I put this together is best practice, or even secure.
It is a FBV that allows users to POST update their profiles by way of using the provided ModelForm.

The view:

```
def profile_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            instance.activity1 = form.cleaned_data.get("activity1")
            instance.activity2 = form.cleaned_data.get("activity2")
            instance.activity3 = form.cleaned_data.get("activity3")
            instance.subject1 = form.cleaned_data.get("subject1")
            instance.subject2 = form.cleaned_data.get("subject2")
            instance.subject3 = form.cleaned_data.get("subject3")
            instance.introduction = form.cleaned_data.get("introduction")

            instance = form.save(commit=False)

            instance.save()
            return redirect('/profile/edit')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user, initial={
            'activity1': Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).activity1,
            'activity2': Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).activity2,
            'activity3': Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).activity3,
            'subject1': Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).subject1,
            'subject2': Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).subject2,
            'subject3': Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).subject3,
            'introduction': Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).introduction,
            })
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'profile_edit.html', context)
```

The form:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    activity1 = forms.CharField(max_length=54, label='Activity 1')
    activity2 = forms.CharField(max_length=54)
    activity3 = forms.CharField(max_length=54)
    subject1 = forms.CharField(max_length=54)
    subject2 = forms.CharField(max_length=54)
    subject3 = forms.CharField(max_length=54)
    introduction = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ProfileForm, self).clean()
        return cleaned_data
```

Is there a better way to get this accomplished? I would think there's a way to retrieve the entire `cleaned` form data at once, and then update the `instance` with the all new POSTed data in fewer statements as well.
And what about pre-populating a form with data already stored in the database? Is querying the DB one by one the usual way to make this work?
I'm not exactly trying to force/hack away the repetition--if it happens to be the conventional Django way of doing things, I'm all good! I simply think I'm misunderstanding something and not doing it in the most Django'ic way possible. 
Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `Meta` class to your form, and `ModelForm` would take care of the rest.

forms.py,

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        exclude = ('user',)
```

views.py,

```
def profile_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('/profile/edit')
    else:
        form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile_edit.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had the Meta tag, but I guess it doesn't work bc it was below the rest of the code.  
Any idea why `profile.save()` might cause this `UNIQUE constraint failed: user_profile_profile.user_id` exception?

Comment: Do you have a one to one relationship with the user in Profile table??

Comment: `class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile_of')`  
and in my User model:  
`class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=24, unique=True, null=True)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile)`  

Actually, I deleted my migrations and started over. I am now getting a `NOT NULL constraint failed` error and unable to even create a superuser :/

Comment: The reason behind the error, is that your current user has already a Profile table associated to it. Django is trying to create new one every time. Does the form contain data in GET request??

Comment: I'm not sure how to find out.. How might my Profile and MyUser relationship be configured in order for every User to have one profile?

Comment: You have defined in your models `profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile)`.

Comment: Any way I have edited my code. Try it. It should edit the existing profile.